# No suitable user-defined conversion from "cv::Matx<double, 2, 1>" to "cv::Vec2d" exists

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2022

I have to perform the following **per-element** product:

```
out = dist * v1 * v2 / res;
```

where:

- `dist` is a scalar (double)
- `v1`, `v2`, `v3` are `cv::Vec2d` (vector of 2 `double`)

My very *easy peasy* code with `opencv`:

```
 #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
 cv::Vec2d test() {
     double dist = 1.0;
     cv::Vec2d v1(1.0, 1.0), v2(1.0, 1.0);
     return (dist * v1).mul(v2).div(v3);
 }
```

The error I got (compiling with `cl.exe` under VC17):

```
E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from "cv::Matx<double, 2, 1>" to "cv::Vec2d" exists
```

Breaking down the operations, the problem is with `.div`, while `.mul` works fine.

Now, looking at the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/dcf/classcv_1_1Vec.html), I can note:

- `cv::Vec<_Tp,cn>` is inherited from `cv::Matx<_Tp,cn,1>`, thus `cv::Vec2d` should be the same as `cv::Matx<double,2,1>`. Am I missing something?
- `cv::Vec<_Tp,cn>` is cited into the doc, but I've not found either the declaration of `cv::Vec<_Tp,cn>::div` nor a mention to it or to the per-element division operation in general. However the method does exists.

Any idea where I'm wrong and how to (easily) fix?

### Side Notes

- Cross-posted on [OpenCV Forum](https://forum.opencv.org/t/no-suitable-user-defined-conversion-from-cv-matx-double-2-1-to-cv-vec2d-exists/11537)
- Issue opened on [GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/23115)

Comment: Regarding your first bullet: yes, but notice the direction of conversion it complains about -- that's base to derived.

Comment: One possible approach: `return cv::Vec2d((dist * v1).mul(v2).div(v3).val);`

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/no-suitable-user-defined-conversion-from-cv-matx-double-2-1-to-cv-vec2d-exists/11537

Comment: @DanMašek, thank you for the suggestion. As far as the casting is concerned, my understanding was that never the operation would falls back to the base (and then forth to the derived). I thought everything should be computed as Vec2d type

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266053/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-a-question-between-non-stack-exchange-and-stack-exchange